# Team city VCS trigger is not starting automatically

Tags: build, triggers, teamcity

Once I commit the change in git, build is not starting automatically in Team city. I have enabled per-checkin triggering(both the check boxes), even after the bbuild is not started automatically(currently im running manually). Can anyone suggest the possible solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you push the change also, after the commit?

Comment: Nope I didn't push after commit in git